# How to use content management software with our own designed website?

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, web-development-server

I am new here and I am learning web development for now. So please don't mind if something is wrong with this post.
So, coming to the question, I came to know about various CMS softwares like wordpress, drupal etc.
They offer some free and paid themes to build a website.
But, I want to design my own website with Bootstrap framework and then use a CMS software to add content everyday. To be clear, I don't want to use themes.
SO, is it possible to make our own design and then integrate to CMS?
Please give some suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. But I suggest you move this question to one of the other Stack Exchange network sites. You won't get much help on this kind of issues on SO.

Comment: Yes, its possible. There are lot of frameworks for that. You can use any one and build your `CMS`

Comment: Hi and Welcome.this question is too broad for stack overflow. You should probably look for some web development tutorials to get the big picture, and come back here for solving specific issues.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, you want to have your own design built with Bootstrap and then use some CMS to get your blog up.

I suggest using WordPress as CMS, and taking any free Bootstrap based WordPress theme and modifying it as per your own design needs, this way you will not have to worry about WordPress theme building learning at this stage.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use Wordpress. You can design your own theme from scratch. Take a look at [Theme Development](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development) on Wordpress. Also, [these video tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLMvLDJ7usmZDsQHpHG8BV90lqtS0Dra_9) should give you a good start. Good luck!